# Does GameObject.GetComponent() find sub classes?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Working in the latest Unity3d 3.5 if it matters.

If I have a set of classes:

```
Class A extends MonoBehaviour
Class B extends Class A
Class C1 extends Class B
Class C2 extends Class B
```

And I have a GameObject that has C2 as a component.  Will `GetComponent.<A>()` return the C2 component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I haven't tried a three-level hierarchy but, for two, I can confirm that GetComponent works as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Also, this can be helpful: try to call

```
gameObjC1.SendMessage("MethodFromA");
```

in case you need to get A just to call its method.